# Installation problem with Atom D2500 Cedarview

Tags: installation, ubuntu-netbook

I just got my netbook yesterday and spent the whole day to get Ubuntu into it.

- Intel Atom D2500, Cedarview, 1.86 GHz, 2 GB RAM.

An error occurred when I tried to install both using WUBI and ISO. The error was **"can't retrieve required installation files"** and it prevented the installation process from completing.

At one point, whenever I try to install, the installation seems finished and it seems like I just need to reboot. But it gets stuck on a black screen afterwards or stuck on commands kernel thread helper. It seems that the Cedarview processor has something to do with the problem.

Has anyone had any experience with this issue or has any solution to it? Please let me know.

Comment: the gma 3500 integrated graphic card didnt support by intel for linux.

Comment: and im still looking for the solution.

Comment: little help anyone?

Answer (score 1):

I have an Intel Atom D2500 (chipset NM10) with 2GB-Ram to.
Actually, it running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS perfectly, but the problem I have support concern the driver for the GMA chipset (GMA 3600/3650 family).
This Chipset are NOT actually functional with Unity 3D, and make some problem (in some case) during the installation.

So I have been obliged to active the Unity-2D and follow some way to fix the screen-size resolution (by following this ):

http://daily.siebler.eu/2012/06/ubuntu-12-04-driver-for-intel-cedarview-atom-n2000-und-d2000-serie/

Wich version of Ubuntu have you try to install? I am under the 12.04 LTS 32 bits, and maybe the problem come when to try to install the 64 bits version.

Comment: When I try to install ubuntu 12.04.5 32bit on an Atom D2500 notebook I booted into black screen...